# Finding a different pattern from the determined pattern

Tags: pattern-recognition

I have set the determined set of pattern that is like this (0.12,0.14,1.00,0.1,1.82), and I want to figure out whether 1000 other sets of 5 points follow the same pattern as the above (which is increasing, then decreasing, and then increasing in the determined pattern).

What kind of algorithms/methods should I try?
The goal is to detect the sets that don't follow the same pattern and behave differently from the determined pattern.

Thanks!

P.s. A quick method using R or Python would be nice.

Comment: First you have to define exactly what you mean by "following the pattern". I thought @StatStudent's answer was excellent, but then you added more detail.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?  Each of the rows is checked for the pattern of increasing, increasing, decreasing, increasing and outputs the results as TRUE or FALSE.

```
x<-data.frame(matrix(runif(1000*5), 1000, 5))
x$results<-(x[2]>x[1] && x[3]>x[2] && x[4]<x[3] && x[5]>x[4])
head(x)

> head(x)
         X1        X2        X3         X4        X5    result
1 0.6812421 0.6179089 0.4677266 0.08470731 0.3105175 FALSE
2 0.3161286 0.9102854 0.9559161 0.14665398 0.1736086  TRUE
3 0.1951060 0.6304466 0.5529309 0.13894793 0.6352741 FALSE
4 0.7696047 0.2728853 0.3892910 0.67016050 0.1315047 FALSE
5 0.4675989 0.1841558 0.9340945 0.22240919 0.5642445 FALSE
6 0.1342969 0.5703942 0.5106183 0.55438823 0.4235319 FALSE
```

Comment: Good answer, but I also care about how large/small increase/decrease is compared to the determined set. Any suggestions?

Comment: I' not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do.  Can you explain further?